# Show console for install4j launchers

Tags: install4j

How to enable [java console](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) for GUI app installed by install4j installer. When I use JNLP mode for my app console work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Java console" setting in the Java 8 control panel has no effect on launchers compiled by install4j.

To get a console, you have to add a console launcher in addition to the GUI launcher.

Alternatively, you can execute the GUI launcher from a console and start it with the

```
-console
```

parameter, then stderr and stdout will be written to the console (without blocking).

Comment: Thank you for fast answer!
Now, I try to use "Allow -console parameter" and also configure redirection, but log files does't appear